# JSP - Sliding Image

Tags: jquery, html

I am using `<marquee>` to slide a image in my jsp page. However, I can't find how to slide a image from right side top to right side bottom of my jsp page. Can anybody help me how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's .animate(). BTW - it's a client side HTML/CSS/JavaScript issue. This has ZERO to do with JSP.

Comment: a vertical marquee you mean? search about vertical carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery's native animate() function:

HTML:

```
<img height="100" width="100" id="box" src="#" />
```

CSS:

```
#box{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}​
```

​jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $theBox = $("#box");
    $theBox.animate({
        top:$(window).height()-$theBox.height()
    }, 1000);
}); ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hNYDe/